# Kong: Luajit not found

Tags: ubuntu, luajit, kong

I'm trying to get `kong` working, but every time I run `kong start` I get a `/usr/local/bin/kong: 3: exec: /usr/local/bin/luajit: not found`, which is weird as I do have `luajit` installed?

My `/usr/local/bin` contains these files:

```
forever   kong   lua2json  luajit-2.0.4  luarocks-5.1    luarocks-admin-5.1
json2lua  lapis  luajit    luarocks      luarocks-admin
```

Anyone else who has installed `kong`, and knows how to get past it? I've searched far and wide, but with no luck.

If it's any help, I'm on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/luajit` say? What about `file /usr/local/bin/luajit`?

Comment: @Etan Reisner it contains a file also called `luajit`

Comment: I'm sorry, what? That's not an answer to either of my questions. I just want the literal command output from you running those two commands.

Comment: Oops sorry! I apparently misread that. Anywho, the `ls - l` command says `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Dec 18 00:04 luajit -> luajit-2.0.4` and the other command says `luajit: symbolic link to `luajit-2.0.4'`

Comment: And the output from both `ls -l` and `file` on `/usr/local/bin/luajit-2.0.4`?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 449336 Dec 18 00:04 luajit-2.0.4` and `luajit-2.0.4: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildI
[sha1]=b1e2350ea2324e0ee0af0750f00ecf5afe77078a, stripped`

Comment: Two more questions. Are you running a 64 bit system? What does `ldd /usr/local/bin/luajit-2.0.4` output?

Comment: Oh, no I'm running 32, which is probably the problem. `ldd` returns `not a dynamic executable`

Comment: I did a clean install and now it works, somehow I had gotten the wrong bit version. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @Mobilpadde can you formally answer this question and mark it as resolved?

Comment: @Mark Sorry, yeah, just did that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow got a wrong bit version of kong, which were the problem the whole time.